# Handling non-url errors

Tags: vb.net, httprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to run the following:

```
Dim a As Boolean = False
        Try
            Dim myHTTPWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(txtToShorten.Text), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim myHTTPwebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHTTPWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            If myHTTPwebResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                a = True
            End If
        Catch e As WebException
        Catch e As Exception
        End Try
        Return a
```

When I do a correct url its works fine and returns true however if the url entered is not valid then it doesnt return a value at.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Hi Mark, apologies but I'm not 100% on the question - is the question about how to detect whether an invalid URL has been provided in `txtToShorten.Text`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this works fine for me:

```
Imports System.Net
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim x As Boolean = bb()
    x = x

End Sub

Private Function bb() As Boolean

    Dim a As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim myHTTPWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http:\\www.fokikkkkkrd.com"), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim myHTTPwebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHTTPWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If myHTTPwebResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            a = True
        End If
    Catch ex As WebException
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return a

End Function
```

End Class

Is did you put this code inside a function??